# How does one detect the action of adding/removing of a UNC share with Delphi? (Prev D7)

Tags: delphi, networking, delphi-7, share, unc

How does one detect the action of adding/removing a UNC share? I basically just need to know if a share has been added/removed not details about the share itself. A working example would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
SB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"By monitoring the registry at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\lanmanserver\Shares\ I can catch changes to it."

To monitor a registry key... http://delphi.about.com/od/kbwinshell/l/aa052003a.htm

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no callback/event mechanism to be notified of such an event so I think you can only enumerate (poll) and compare to the previous state at intervals.

(or the ugly way: hook WNetAddConnection* and WNetCancelConnection* API's)

Comment: OK, I found another way.
By monitoring the registry at 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\lanmanserver\Shares\ I can catch changes to it. 

Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @SoulBlade: You should provide that answer as a "normal" answer and not as a comment. Then people can vote on it (an you can accept it).

Comment: BTW I thought you wanted to monitor adding/removing a connection to a share (a mapped drive) so my answer doesn't really address your question.

Comment: :-(
Ja, I just wanted to know if someone is sharing (or removing it) a folder. I thought windows might have a message for that.